# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent number of samples: [14508, 1]

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

So i'm trying to train a multiple linear regression model and I am trying to input xTrain and yTrain. xTrain is made of two features whilst y is just a single label.

xTrain is in the form [[a, b], [c, d]] and yTrain is in the form of [[e, f]].

I did model.fit(xTrain, [yTrain]) # yTrain was a 1d array so I converted to 2d.

There are the same number of x and y values (2 features per y value)!

Why is it giving the error in the title and how can I fix it?

Comment: please post a minimum reproducible example and the stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Because the number of rows in xTrain and yTrain should be the same,

So for example let say I have 10 rows and 5 columns in the xTrain, the yTrain should have 10 rows

And you don't need to convert the yTrain to be 2d array, 1d array is fine,

model.fit(xTrain, yTrain) will work just fine.

Comment: what do you mean by number of rows because in the example I provided with a and b... each y value has exactly two corresponding x values which is what is shown no?